# Using python to create relations in Neo4j but not all are created

Tags: python, database, error-handling, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to create relationships on a graph I have on neo4j. When i run the python code, it runs through the excel file and for every row it created a relationship based on the two id columns. However not all of them are created.

For example when I run one excel file that has 33k rows, only 7.5k edges are created in the database.

I have checked that the process is running correctly, that the correct values are passed each time on the correct function/var so I really can't think of what is the issue here.

Below there are my code as well as a screen from the excel file so that you can see its structure.

Code:

```
my_set = set()
graph = Graph(url,password=password)
tx = graph.begin()
rels = list()
filename = input('Give file name --- ')
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'id1', 'id2']
if filename.startswith('attack'):
    rel_type = 'ATTACKS'
elif filename.startswith('trade'):
    rel_type = 'TRADES'
else:
    rel_type = 'MESSAGES'
row_cnt = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row_cnt = row_cnt + 1
    if row_cnt%1000 == 0 : print('Computed '+ str(row_cnt))
    t1 = datetime.now()
    ts = int(row['Timestamp'])
    formatted_ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    splitted_ts = formatted_ts.split()
    date = splitted_ts[0]
    time = splitted_ts[1]  

    node1 = graph.evaluate('MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.id={id} RETURN n', id=int(row["id1"]))
    node2 = graph.evaluate('MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.id={id} RETURN n', id=int(row['id2']))
    rels.append(Relationship(node1, rel_type, node2, date=date, time=time))

print('FileFInished************')
print('Computed ' + str(row_cnt))
edge_cnt = 0
for v in rels:
    edge_cnt = edge_cnt + 1
    if edge_cnt%1000==0: print('edge count: ', edge_cnt)
    tx.create(v)
tx.commit()
print('edges: ' + str(edge_cnt))
```

Excel file(3 columns, could not post picture sorry):

```
____________________________
|Timestamp| userId1 | userId2|
------------------------------
|123342312| 3123    | 12312  |
|33121123 | 332     | 21231  |
```

Comment: I find your question really interesting, but please [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is very hard to help you otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that some of the `id1` or `id2` values have no corresponding `User` nodes in the DB?